# Form submits regardless of validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form, and I've written a validation script for it, however, it's not working 100%. It outputs errors fine, but the submit button will submit the form, even if it has outputted the alert boxes. Anyone have any idea why?

Apparently not all the code pasted. I would just use the Required parameter, but I need JS validation as it is an assignment. Also, UL is defined before this part of code, as there is a list before this.

HTML:

```
<div class = "form">
            <form name = "contactForm" onsubmit="validateForm()" action = "form.php">

            <li><label>First name: </label><input type = "text" name = "fname" autofocus></li><br>

            <li><label>Last Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "lname"></li><br>

            <li><label>Email: </label><input type = "text" name = "email"> <button onclick = "validateEmail();return false">Check if email is valid</button> </li><br>

            <li><label>Message: </label> <br>

                <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "message"></textarea></li>

            <li> <input type = "submit"> </li>

            </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm()
{
  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["fname"].value; //Gets the form and field name from the HTML

  if (x==null || x=="") //If the field "fname" contains null, or nothing, then output an alert telling the user to input something into the field. Same goes for the rest of the code.
  {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["lname"].value;

  if (x==null || x=="") 
  {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    return false; 
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;

  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 

  if(reg.test(x) == false)
  {
      alert("Please enter a valid Email");
      return false;
  }

  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;

  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("Message must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you attaching the event listener?

Comment: How are you triggering the validate function?  If it's not bound to the form's `submit` **event** (not the submit button click), then it's not going to stop the form submission.

Comment: You know your markup is totally invalid, there's no UL etc ?

Comment: @cale_b never bind events to buttons that are meant for submit - not all users click buttons. Submit is the correct event to bind a function to.

Comment: @Popnoodles - that was my point exactly.  The code would not work if that was how the event was bound.

Comment: @Popnoodles: That is what @cale_b said. (But for what it’s worth, browsers will fire `click` on submit buttons regardless of how the form was submitted if there’s only one.)

Comment: @cale_b Oh, I thought you were suggesting he/she *should* bind it to a button.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to trigger event on time of submit. Like this way:**

`<form onsubmit="validateForm()">`

Answer (score 1):

How are you attaching the event listener? I’d wager it’s with:

```
<form … onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

You’d need `return validateForm()`. But wait! Don’t add that.

Your script does not check for valid e-mail addresses correctly. It only checks one error at once. It will annoy users. Use HTML5 validation and back it up with PHP.

- By applying `type="email"`, you don’t need a button at all, and mobile users will see an e-mail specific keyboard if available. The browser will validate it, given support.

  ```
  <input type="email" name="email">
  ```
- Required fields should use the `required` attribute.

  ```
  <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus required>
  ⋮
  <input type="text" name="lname" required>
  ```

Your labels aren’t correct either; they should surround the element they’re related to, or provide a `for` attribute matching the element’s `id`.

You should also validate your HTML. And not put `<br>`s between `<li>`s.

Finally, as general [client-side] JavaScript tips:

- You don’t have to check the `value` of a text field for `null`.
- Write `!x` instead of `x == false`.

Comment: @Johan: `undefined` doesn’t stop a form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery to do something like this:

```
    $( "#formId" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if($("#nameInput").val() == "")
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

So basically, if nameInput's equals to empty the submit action will be canceled

Take a look at here if you want: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Good luck